# in yasnippet, how to insert variable date with fixed time of day?

Tags: org-mode, yasnippet, time-date

I want a yasnippet to insert an org-mode date and time.

The date should be today's date, but the time should be fixed.

So far my snippet correctly inserts today's date, but not the time:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: jdt 
# key: jdt
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --

* TODO meditate
  SCHEDULED: `(let ((x (org-insert-time-stamp (current-time)))))`
```

How do I get the time (8:30am) inside the timestamp?

Desired output:

```
* TODO meditate
  SCHEDULED: <2015-09-18 Fri 8:30am>
```

Comment: It's not an answer to the question you asked, but you might also consider using [repeating tasks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html). That way you get the behavior you want (if it repeats on a fixed schedule), but you also get all the logging of those tasks in one place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `format-time-string` function to format the time in different ways, for your example this should work:

```
* TODO meditate
  SCHEDULED: `(format-time-string "<%Y-%m-%d %a 8:30am>" (current-time))`
```

Comment: I don't want the current time, I want a fixed time, 8:30am. Also the let is necessary otherwise yasnippet inserts the timestamp twice.

Comment: Creating a todo list for the day and scheduling all of my tasks for the exact same time (the time I create the list) would be insane. The whole point of scheduling in the first place is so I can plan when to do things throughout the day—meditate at 8:30am, gym at 9:00am, etc.

Comment: @incandescentman Ok, now I understand. I have updated the post.